# Retrieve sentinel2 cloud mask through an API

Tags: python, api, satellite, cloud-cover

Have you ever heard about an API to download sentinel2 cloud mask only ? Not all bands but just cloud mask. Because I just want to process a small part of each satellite tile and it's very time consuming to download plenty of tiles full of cloud. The average cloud information per tile does not fit my expectation.

For the moment I download all the bands and cloud mask through this API : [Sentinel-download](https://github.com/olivierhagolle/Sentinel-download)

Comment: I did not try it and it is not an API by itself, but there is a plugin for QGIS called "SentinelHub". Maybe worth a look.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I need an API to retrieve cloud mask automatically. Moreover this extension doesn't allow to get only cloud mask...